# I exceeded my bandwidth limit in Firebase Storage

Tags: firebase, firebase-storage

I exceeded my Firebase Storage bandwidth limit (1gb per day) now I wanna know how blaze works, and what I have to buy. I saw in Blaze's calculator that Storage has three options GB stored, GB transferred and Operations.

Which one I need to buy?

I choose the number I want or it bills on demand depending of the use?

If i buy 60gb and reach this limit the app will continue working?

What is bandwidth exactly? is when I read something:?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When you upgrade your Firebase project to the paid/Blaze plan, you don't prepay for a certain amount of usage. Instead you pay for all usage of resources on your project that goes beyond the free quota.

So for Cloud Storage you pay for:

- The amount of data that is stored in the buckets of your project.
- The amount of data that is read from the buckets of your project.
- The number of operations performed against the buckets of your project.

That second one is bandwidth: it's the amount of data that is read from your Storage buckets. If you have an image of 1MB in storage, and it's read by 60 users, that would be:

- 1MB of storage
- 60MB of bandwidth
- 60 read operations

There' a handy pricing calculator at the bottom of the Firebase [pricing page](https://firebase.google.com/pricing) to see how the cost works out for your usage.

Comment: Is there a way to minimize the costs of bandwidth?

Comment: Given the formula: download fewer files, downloading for fewer users, or make the files smaller.